# Reinstallling WSUS After full removal failure

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-10

I am running 2 servers on Windows Server 2012 R2. One of them is running a WSUS Server. The server running the WSUS server can search for updates and it Shows it needs to download and install updates. When you click install, it states that it has to download XXXmb of updates and then errors out saying error 8024402C.

Group policy has Delivery Optimization set to Bypass (100). I have the group policy set to the http://wsusserver:8530 set. It is set for automatically install. I don't see any glaring info in the log other than it can't download from the internet which I have disabled through group policy. It can reach the IIS site without a problem which means it is not a firewall issue. What could I be missing? I am testing on the other Server 2012 R2 server as well. Same seems to be happening on the Windows 10 computers on the system. They are showing in WSUS as needing updates and they show as a successful checkin to the server but not downloading updates.

Server version is 6.3.9600.18324

**EDIT**: Other server getting the exact same issue which leads me to believe it is the WSUS server that is the culprit.

**EDIT**: Found the following errors in my WindowsUpdate.log

```
Error 8024402C occurred while downloading update; notifying dependent calls.
Failed to get Wu Exemption inform from NLM. Assuming not exempt: 80240337
Hit Transient Error 80072EE7
Download Call Complete 8024402C
```

**EDIT:** Now the server is not checking in with the WSUS server. I removed it from the list of computers and waiting for it to check back in and report. It will not report. I am not running a proxy sever and port 8530 is allowed through the firewall. What could be causing this?

**EDIT:** This error seems to come up every time it checks for updates in the log `GetCurrentNetworkCostPolicy Failed Error 80240037`. I also see one saying `FATAL: BeginInteractiveInstalled failed 8024402C` Still can't find a cause yet.

**EDIT:** Was able to run the Powershell script to install the WSUS feature. Clean removed WSUS, WID, IIS and cleaned registry and files and restarted before running the powershell command. Now I am getting an issue where I can't get WSUS postinstall to complete. It gets to the following and then says failed to complete.

```
10:30:34  Configuring IIS...
10:30:35  Start: ConfigureWebsite
10:30:36  Configuring website on port 8530
10:30:39  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UseCustomWebSite.ExecuteIisCustomAction(String arguments)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UseCustomWebSite.Install(Int32 portNumber)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UseCustomWebSite.InstallAndConfigure(IisConfiguration& iisConfiguration, Int32 newPortNumber)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.ConfigureWebsite(Int32 portNumber)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Run()
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Execute(String[] arguments)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me that there is some network connection related issue. Are you using any proxy, etc. to access Internet?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful negative. Not using a proxy. This is very strange. I can remote to the server. I can ping the server.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `automatically detect settings` is checked in LAN settings (Internet options), in the client computers which are to take updates from WSUS?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Yes I can confirm it is set to auto detect.